# How can I add a Shortcut to my Apple Watch Home screen?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, siri, shortcuts-app

I want to enable/disable my iPhone's Cellular Data using my Apple Watch. Here's what I've done so far:

1) Created two Shortcuts, one to enable, and another to disable Cellular Data.

2) Added these two Shortcuts to Siri.

Doing these two steps have enabled me to ask Siri on my Apple Watch to enable/disable Cellular Data on the iPhone.

But, I want to execute these Shortcuts without Siri. Is it possible to add a link to a Shortcut on the Apple Watch Home screen? I know that's possible on the iPhone, but haven't found a way to do it on the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible.  Shortcut icons on the iOS home screen are not technically "Apps" and the Apple Watch home screen only shows apps which you choose to show from the "Available Apps" section in the iOS Watch app.

For now, you'll have to continue using Siri.